# How to refresh a GTK image?

Tags: c, gtk, opencl

Hi people from Stackoverflow, I have some knowledge of programming, but not very much. My idea is to program something like a video-game or visualizer in c, to do so I make and process somehow an array that represents an image and it has to be visualized and always being refreshed, like a video-game. I have the algorithm already done, I need to optimize it, I mean I know how to create the array representing an image at anytime, what I need now is to visualize it like an animation and later optimize with opencl.
The program that I want to make has to do something like this:
"create the image" 
"render it",
"create the image" 
"render it",
...
For that reason I know that I could start easily from a very simple example and I don't have to learn everything of GTK. I have been intensively searching for simple examples and trying to understand how it works but it didn't help, I need just to do that simple action, refresh it. A command somewhere should be enough.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <glib.h>
const int Width = 1200, Height = 800;
char *buffer;

int i = 0;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget* image;


void delay(int number_of_seconds){
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    buffer = (char*)malloc(3 * Width * Height);

    // CREATE AN IMAGE IN BUFFER SOMEHOW
    // buffer = something; 
    // 

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data (buffer, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, Width, Height, (Width)*3, NULL, NULL);
    image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pixbuf);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Visualizador");
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    delay(0.04);
    gtk_main ();
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The program is really simple, when I create/load the image there it shows a picture, but I would like to put the function already programmed there, to return a "buffer" and then refresh the displayed image. 
I read that `gtk_widget_queue_draw` has something to do, or `gdk_pixbuf_simple_anim_add_frame` or `g_timeout_add` but I have no idea how they work and what to put in this program.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a moving image or something that needs to get refreshed a lot then I would suggest using a GtkDrawingArea and implement it's draw signal, for that you'll need to use cairo. It should look something like this:

```
static gboolean
your_draw_cb(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *context, gpointer data)
{
  // Do your drawing
  return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
  // Some code before ...
  GtkWidget *area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(area), "draw", G_CALLBACK(your_draw_cb), your_data);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(your_container), area);
  // More code ...
}
```

Each time you want to refresh it you should call

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw(area);
```

to get the draw signal called.

You won't need to store a buffer as that comes inside the cairo context.

But you may want to use other libraries for this purpose, like SDL2 or OpenGL as they are designed for videogames.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As an aditional note, OpenCL is for general programming, not for graphics

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use GtkDrawingArea. And to make the image I have to process other ones, that process is a little complicated but it is done separately for each pixel. And it takes a while until the processor makes the images, for that reason I think it is a good idea to use opencl to use the video card and make the image faster.